# Div content align center don't work

Tags: html, css

I trie to center the content inside one of my divs but i can't.
I tried with margin:0 auto; and with text-align: center but nothing is changeing.
How can i make the social buttons to be in the center of the social div ?
Thanks in advance !

My code:

```css
.list{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}


.social{
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.social__btn{
  background:#ccc;
  color:#fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width:68px;
  height:50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  padding:25px 5px 5px 5px;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
}


.profile__bio{
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
  color:#000;
}
  .bio__item{
    margin-bottom: 8px;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="profile__bio list">
       
        <li class="bio__item">
          <span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span>
          <p>Some text</p>
        </li>
        <li class="bio__item">
          <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
          <p>Some text</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
<ul class="social list">
        <a href=""><li class="social__btn fb"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></li></a>
        <a href=""><li class="social__btn linkedin"><span class="fa fa-linkedin"></span></li></a>
        <a href=""><li class="social__btn insta"><span class="fa fa-instagram"></span></li></a>
      </ul>
```

Comment: I don't see any `<div>` in your markup at all. In addition, your HTML is invalid.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apply `display: inline-block;` to your `.social__btn` elements, erase `float: left` from them and apply `text-align-center` to the `.social` `ul` container, which will center the inline-blocks inside it.

```css
.list{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}


.social{
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.social__btn{
  background:#ccc;
  color:#fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width:68px;
  height:50px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding:25px 5px 5px 5px;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
}


.profile__bio{
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
  color:#000;
}
  .bio__item{
    margin-bottom: 8px;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="profile__bio list">
       
        <li class="bio__item">
          <span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span>
          <p>Some text</p>
        </li>
        <li class="bio__item">
          <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
          <p>Some text</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
<ul class="social list">
        <a href=""><li class="social__btn fb"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></li></a>
        <a href=""><li class="social__btn linkedin"><span class="fa fa-linkedin"></span></li></a>
        <a href=""><li class="social__btn insta"><span class="fa fa-instagram"></span></li></a>
      </ul>
```

Comment: His question is about a div element and there is no div in his, or your, markup. So how can you call this an answer? On top of that, the HTML is invalid!

Comment: @Rob There's no use to nitpicking. " How can i make the social buttons to be in the center of the social div? "  is a pretty clear question

Comment: Thanks, the problem was the float:left on the social_btn class.

Comment: This is the first time on SO I have ever heard someone say trying to fix non-existant, invalid HTML is "nit picking".

Comment: @Rob so now you had to vote down an accepted answer because you don't like the question?

Comment: Because you should not dilute the quality of SO by answering an off topic question as stated in the Help Center. It's one of the reasons why I no longer answer questions here. Because even high rep people are doing that and lowering the quality of SO overall. I have all but given up.

Answer (score 0):

`text-align:center` has to go on the container, and the icons can't float left, I think.. Anyway, this seems to work:

```css
.list{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}


.social{
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.social__btn{
  background:#ccc;
  color:#fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width:68px;
  height:50px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding:25px 5px 5px 5px;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
}


.profile__bio{
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
  color:#000;
}
  .bio__item{
    margin-bottom: 8px;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="profile__bio list">
       
        <li class="bio__item">
          <span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span>
          <p>Some text</p>
        </li>
        <li class="bio__item">
          <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
          <p>Some text</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
<ul class="social list">
       <li class="social__btn fb"> <a href=""><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a></li>
        <li class="social__btn linkedin"><a href=""><span class="fa fa-linkedin"></span></a></li>
        <li class="social__btn insta"><a href=""><span class="fa fa-instagram"></span></a></li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: His question is about a div element and there is no div in his, or your, markup. So how can you call this an answer?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
.social {
   text-align: center;
   //other css...
}

.social a {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
.list{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}


.social{
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.social a {
  display: inline-block;
}

.social__btn{
  background:#ccc;
  color:#fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width:68px;
  height:50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  padding:25px 5px 5px 5px;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
}


.profile__bio{
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
  color:#000;
}
  .bio__item{
    margin-bottom: 8px;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="profile__bio list">
       
        <li class="bio__item">
          <span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span>
          <p>Some text</p>
        </li>
        <li class="bio__item">
          <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
          <p>Some text</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
<ul class="social list">
        <a href=""><li class="social__btn fb"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></li></a>
        <a href=""><li class="social__btn linkedin"><span class="fa fa-linkedin"></span></li></a>
        <a href=""><li class="social__btn insta"><span class="fa fa-instagram"></span></li></a>
</ul>
```

Comment: His question is about a div element and there is no div in his, or your, markup. So how can you call this an answer?

Comment: In addition, this HTML is invalid!

Comment: Rob,you are right, but i guess,meaning of  `social buttons`  is `a` tags.

Comment: For answering an off topic question that should be closed and not answered.

Comment: @Rob, I'm sorry for your thinking!

Comment: It is "thinking" as outlined in the Help Center.

Comment: [Per the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote), "...voting on questions and answers is the primary mechanism through which the community governs the site on a day to day basis." Which is my basis for downvoting. However, it goes on to say, "...voting down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information.", which is not true. I made my point so I will retract the vote. I hope you downvoted the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following CSS.Here I have used display:flex and margin:auto. Hope this will help.

```
.social__btn{
  background:#ccc;
  color:#fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width:68px;
  height:50px;
  display: flex;
  margin:auto;
  padding:25px 5px 5px 5px;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
}
```